# OneToOne Double Bidirectional Association

Tags: java, jpa, uml, one-to-one, model-associations

I am newbie to UML diagrams and would like to code the following one, where there is an  OneToOne double bidirectional association, with JPA annotations.

[image: Double OneToOne association]

*Context: there are persons and teams. Each team is composed of persons and each person can only belong to one team. The teams have always a person acting as main Leader and optionally can have a second Leader.*

Based on this [page](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/), I have written the code below but I am not sure if it is right.

```
@Entity
public class Person extends BaseEntity {

...

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="mainLeader", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Team mainTeam;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="secondLeader", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Team secondTeam;    
}

@Entity
public class Team extends BaseEntity {

...

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    private Person mainLeader;

    @OneToOne
    private Person secondLeader;    
}
```

Comment: Feels like you are looking for a bi-directional relationship but the question is not really clear.are you trying to map mainTeam and secondTeam to one leader ? What are you looking to do in simple terms?

Comment: @mujibishola I want to code this double association with JPA annotations. That is all.

Comment: It's not a double association. The `Person` only needs to know about one `Team`. You don't show how it would be associated with a `main` and `second` `Team`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I have written my code based on an example to map an OneToOne bidirectional association that I found on Internet. Please, could you rewrite the right solution or show me an example code?

Comment: Looks good to me (though I don't know jpa).

Comment: Probably but can you add a link to the example you're referring to and add a verbal explanation of the problem description like: There are Teams and every team has ... There are Persons and every person is on *exactly two teams* ...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I have already added a link and a contextual explanation.

Comment: Your class diagram seems flawed. It states that each person will always be associated to two teams (multiplicity on the side of the team is '1'). That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 3):

The association names suggests roles to be  used. `Main Leader` might correspond to a role `mainLeader`. So I would just create a property in `Team`.

But since the associations are just named and do not have roles you are open to create roles at wish. This should be derived from the context.

Answer (score 0):

Your entity class code with JPA-annotated mutual reference properties for the two one-to-one bidirectional associations looks pretty good. It's only your class diagram that doesn't look very good because you don't use the names of the reference properties (such as `mainLeader`) for the corresponding association ends, and you don't use *association end ownership dots* for indicating that an association end will be implemented as a corresponding property in the class at the other side.

You can find the following example for bidirectional associations in [Chapter 15](http://web-engineering.info/tech/JavaJpaJsf/book/ch15.html) of the open access book *Building Back-End Web Apps with Java, JPA and JSF*.

[image: Two bidirectional associations]

In the `Publisher` class, we add the `publishedBooks` property and we use the `@OneToMany` annotation corresponding to `@ManyToOne` from the `Book` class, representing the inverse relation:

```
@Entity
public class Publisher { 
  ...
  @OneToMany( fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="publisher")
  private Set<Book> publishedBooks;
  ...
}
```

The `mappedBy` parameter of the `@OneToMany` annotation of the `Publisher`::`publishedBooks` property specifies the property that implements the `@ManyToOne` relation in the `Book` class:

```
@Entity
public class Book { 
  ...
  @ManyToOne( fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn( name="PUBLISHER_NAME")
  private Publisher publisher;
  ...
}
```

In the Author class we add the `authoredBooks` property with the `@ManyToMany` annotation corresponding to `@ManyToMany` from the `Book` class representing the inverse relation:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
  ...
  @ManyToMany( fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="authors")
  private Set<Book> authoredBooks;
  ...
}
```

The `mappedBy` property of the `@ManyToMany` annotation for `Author`::`authoredBooks` specifies the property `name` which implements the `@ManyToMany` relation in the `Book` class:

```
@Entity...
public class Book {
  ...
  @ManyToMany( fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable( name="books_authors", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name="BOOK_ISBN") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name="AUTHOR_PERSONID") })
  private Set<Author> authors;
  ...
}
```

We also use the `@JoinTable` annotation to specify the join table name for the mny-to-many relation and the corresponding column names for the join table (e.g., the table is `books_authors` and the columns are named `BOOK_ISBN` and `AUTHOR_PERSONID`).

Answer (score -1):

I think this solution might be more proper to describe the model.

```
   @Entity
    public class Person extends BaseEntity {

            ...

            @NotNull
            @OneToOne
            private Team team;          
        }

        @Entity
        public class Team extends BaseEntity {

            ...

            @NotNull
            @OneToOne(mappedBy="team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
            private Person mainLeader;

            @OneToOne(mappedBy="team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
            private Person secondLeader;    
        }
```

Comment: Your code is not "more proper", but rather messing it all up! (1) You can't link two different reference properties (mainLeader and secondLeader) to the same inverse property. (2) Your `Person`::`team` property represents a team membership association, while the `Team`::`mainLeader` (and `secondLeader`) properties represent leadership associations.

Comment: @gwag I did not know if it is right or not. I am trying and waiting for a solution that fits in with the uml diagram.

Comment: But the code you provide in your question does fit with your class diagram. There are only some questions if your class diagram is done in the right way (like having mandatory instead of optional association ends at the `Team` side).

Comment: I deleted my answer; sorry if it added confusion. I was looking deeper into your spec than is required to answer your question. I returned today to add a snippet example but I think the changes to do it may go beyond what is needed or permitted without seeing the spec and uml in total. gwag is correct that the changes you made will not work.